# Hyperledger Fabric - Peer executable not found

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I can't start the test-network from Fabric samples, and it seems that the problem is that I can't execute the peer command:

```
localhost:~/fabric-samples/bin$ ls -l
total 212636
-rwxr-xr-x    1 daniele  daniele   21002048 Jun  1 14:43 configtxgen
-rwxr-xr-x    1 daniele  daniele   17543558 Jun  1 14:43 configtxlator
-rwxr-xr-x    1 daniele  daniele   13421747 Jun  1 14:43 cryptogen
-rwxr-xr-x    1 daniele  daniele   18037158 Jun  1 14:43 discover
-rwxr-xr-x    1 daniele  daniele   22950608 May 14 21:23 fabric-ca-client
-rwxr-xr-x    1 daniele  daniele   30278008 May 14 21:24 fabric-ca-server
-rwxr-xr-x    1 daniele  daniele   12421800 Jun  1 14:43 idemixgen
-rwxr-xr-x    1 daniele  daniele   32354840 Jun  1 14:43 orderer
-rwxr-xr-x    1 daniele  daniele   49708904 Jun  1 14:43 peer
localhost:~/fabric-samples/bin$ ./peer
-ash: ./peer: not found
localhost:~/fabric-samples/bin$ echo $PATH
/home/daniele/fabric-samples/bin:/home/daniele/fabric-samples/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Has somebody had a similar problem?
The OS is Alpine Linux.

Thanks

Comment: first try `peer`. then to check the location of peer try `which peer` or `whereis peer`. In my case `peer` is in `/usr/local/bin/peer`. your `PATH` is fine.

Comment: `which peer` returns `/home/daniele/fabric-samples/bin/peer` which seems correct to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem myself.
The library ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 was missing in Alpine so I installed it:

```
apk add libc6-compat
```

Now the executables in bin folder work correctly.